# Varnish, some url's redirecting to :8080 in phpbb?

Tags: nginx, redirect, varnish, phpbb3

I'm using a LEMP server with Varnish so nginx is on :8080 and varnish is cached on :80. The mail site works brilliant, no redirects etc but in a sub folder I have a phpBB forum installed, some of the links in the forum are being redirected to http://domain.com:8080/forum instead of http://domain.com/forum where they should be going.

I have added

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

to my main nginx.conf but this only seems to work on the main site and doesn't work in the phpBB sub folder.

Does anyone know a solution to stop phpBB redirecting to :8080 ?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20708441/4116912) may help. There's also a config option in phpBB `server_port` in the database, set that to 80.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was in the phpbb server settings I had already set it to port 80 but I didn't check the box that said "force settings server wide" after checking the box it now forces port 80 :) thanks for the suggestion though.